# HTML support in Cortona BOT Framework

Tags: bots, botframework, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

We have hosted our own webchat version and enabled HTML into it.
We are now working on Cortana integration, but it seems that Cortana does not support HTML. Is it possible to enable HTML in Cortana, If not then is there any other alternative solution available?

Thank you.

Comment: If Cortana does not support HTML, how could you possibly enable HTML in Cortana?

Comment: You are right, I mean is there any alternative to it.

Answer (score 1):

Cortana does not currntly support HTML, but it does support "cards".

Docs for cards:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-rich-cards

Some cards, such as "adaptive cards" offer support on a per-channel basis, which Cortana is not one.